# openID component for cakePHP (and an easy way to Google)?

Tags: php, cakephp, openid

I have integrated the openID component for cakePHP from http://code.42dh.com/openid/ into my application. When I put in my openID URL (http://openid-provider.appspot.com/XXXXXXXXX ) I am prompted to log into Google from the openID page which and I get properly redirected back to my page with a whole lot of stuff in the GET string and a "successfully authenticated" message so I know that is all OK.

However this requires one to know the URL at lead of time. How can I go directly to a screen to enter one's username and password?

[Sorry if this sounds like a beginner's question, I am still trying to figure this out]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't: the username and password are for the OpenID system that the user is logging into, and you need the URL to specify which system.

You could hard-code this to use the Google OpenID provider but your best bet would be to copy the StackOverflow login page and have 'click here to login with Google', 'click here to login with Yahoo' links that use the default Google OpenID URLs, etc.

Comment: How do you use the Google OpenID?

Comment: Doc here: http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html#endpoint It looks like you use https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id as your OpenID URL

Comment: Wow, those docs are pretty complicated, I'm not really sure I understand what to do here.